# What does appending [0] to methods in python do?

Tags: python

What does appending [0] to methods in python do?
For example, in the following [0] is appended to a method.

```
print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

Comment: It returns the first element of `sys.exc_info()`.

Comment: `print sys.exc_info()[0]` is the equivalent of `info = sys.exc_info();  print info[0]`

Comment: You already have the `print` there, so print it once without `[0]`, once with it and see the difference.

Comment: You should learn about expressions and operators.

Comment: Do you know what `my_list[0]` does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It calls the method and gets the 0th element from the returned value.

```
>>> def test():
...   return ['item0', 'item1']
...
>>> test()
['item0', 'item1']
>>> test()[0]
'item0'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

It means that `sys.exc_info()` returns some collection(e.g. list, tuple, or dictionary with int keys) and you print its first element.

Comment: and for the OP's reference, see here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info

Comment: Not just "some collection", it must be a list, tuple, or dictionary with `int` keys.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- Or any other object with an appropriately defined `__getitem__` ... e.g. `xrange` would fit the bill as well ...

Comment: @MarkRansom As for the dictionary: It doesn't need int keys. It only needs to have *one* key: `0`, the others are irrelevant.

Comment: @all let's not get too pedantic I have simply put an `e.g. list, tuple, or dictionary with int keys`, which I believe is good enough to give a sense of what type for instance can the collection be.

Answer (score 0):

If a method returned an [iterable/indexable collection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) then it will retrieve the first results from that [collection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) (the result which is in position 0)

For example:

```
print sys.exc_info()
> ['item1', 'item2','item3']

print sys.exc_info()[0]
> 'item1'

print sys.exc_info()[2]
> 'item3'
```

Comment: I don't think so. Iterable is not enough; it must be indexable. OTOH, it does not need to be a collection; a `tuple` or `list` would be enough.

Comment: Is a tuple or list not a collection?!?

Checkout the first line of the collections link in my answer : 'This module implements specialized container datatypes providing alternatives to Python’s general purpose built-in containers, dict, list, set, and tuple.'

Comment: As you say - this `collection` module provides alternatives to the built-in ones. The built-in ones cont come from this module, so they are no "collections". [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) is shown what is needed to emulate a sequence.